# How did this number become this datetime?

Tags: t-sql, logic, type-conversion

We have a vendor which one field in the database is a number and somehow in the app interface it shows the date,

I'm trying to figure out how is this conversion

Here is the data:

this number 15862   generates  this date 06/05/2013

I have no idea how, the vendor told us it is NOT a custom logic conversion it was used a tsql function although I can't figure which one.

I tried using "convert" without success.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that's from a tsql function considering it's derived using the UNIX time epoch. Basically it's number of days since 1969-12-31

But you could get it using tsql like so:

```
select datediff(d,'1969-12-31','2013-06-05')
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it's using a base-date of 1/1/1970 (actually 12/31/1969) and the number represents the number of days after that.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably this is saved as an offset in days since 01/01/1979:

date('m/d/Y', 15862*3600*24) gives 06/06/2013 and

date('m/d/Y', 15862*3600*24-(3600*24) gives exactly 06/05/2013